# aggregate data-frame by team in r

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I have a data-frame "dat" that this similar to the following:

```
team   a   b   c
1      5   6   2
1      2   8   1
1      5   10  30
2      1   3   55
2      4   4   4
2      6   11  66
3      10  1   .5
3      3   4   24
3      4   44  60
```

I am trying to turn this into a data-frame so that the mean of each variable (a,b, and c) is calculated for each team.  So that the final result looks like:

```
team    a    b    c
1       4    8    11
2       3.7  6    41.7
3       5.7  16.3 28.2
```

They don't all have to be to 1 decimal, but the point is the same.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can some either `dplyr/data.table` or `base R` `aggregate` to do this.

Using `dplyr`, we group by 'team' and then with `summarise_each`, we get the `mean`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
   group_by(team) %>%
   summarise_each(funs(mean))
```

---

Or in `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(dat)`), grouped by 'team', we loop with `lapply` to get the 'mean' of the other columns.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, lapply(.SD, mean), team]
```

---

Or we can use the formula method of `aggregate` from `base R` to get the `mean`.  We have to specify `.` at the LHS of the formula to signify all other columns.

```
aggregate(.~team, dat, mean)
```