# applying function to data frame in uneven steps

Tags: r, aggregate, apply

I have a data frame that documents the repeated measurements (X4), in column 2 for a set of samples in column 1 and the number of times the measurement was repeated in column 3- 'rep'.

```
head(df1)
       col1    col2    rep
1      AE01    0.20      1
2      AE01    0.28      2
3      AE01    0.52      3
4      AE01    0.02      4
5      AE02    0.19      1
6      AE02    0.40      2
```

I want to make a new matrix/data frame that gets the average of each of the four replicates for each quadruplet of replicated measurements. My attempt is as follows:

```
df2<-cbind(unique(df1$col1), apply(df1$col2[seq(1, length(df1$col2), 4)], 1, mean))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in apply(df1$col2[seq(1, length(df1$col2), 4)], 1, mean) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

This may be due to the fact that I had to remove NA values from the dataset with 'na.omit' earlier and hence there may not be 4 replicates for each of the samples documented in column 1...

How do I get the average for each sample if the step-size is not even for each sample?

Expected output:

```
     sample     calculated_average_of_each_quadruplet_of_col2_values    
1      AE01                                                     0.255      
2      AE02                                                     0.295
```

Comment: `with(df1, ave(col2, col1, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE))` possibly?

Comment: the expected output has been included

Comment: Re-corrected the expected output specifying that the output second column is the average of the quadruplets of replicated measurements for each sample

Comment: sorry that was just an example value- not the real calculated average of the quadruplet. I marked the answer below as best. it shows what I needed

Comment: @johnnyutah I've edited the expected output to show correct results as the dummy values were strongly misleading. (At least, you should have stated that the values were just placeholders and not the expected figures.)

Comment: BTW: There are a lot of duplicates here on SO, e.g, [aggregate data-frame by team in r](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32292696/3817004), [Aggregate a data frame per unique value of a column](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32639319/3817004), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without further imports, this can be done with a number of included functions like tapply or aggregate:

```
aggregate(df1$col2, by=list(df1$col1), function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))
```

results in

```
  Group.1     x
1    AE01 0.255
2    AE02 0.295
```

go with tapply if you want a vector or a list as your result

```
> tapply(df1$col2, df1$col1, function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))
 AE01  AE02 
0.255 0.295
```

Answer (score 2):

With `data.table` my approach would be

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1) # convert to data table by reference
df1[, .(mean_col2 = mean(col2, na.rm = TRUE)), by = col1]
```

Result:

```
   col1 mean_col2
1: AE01     0.255
2: AE02     0.295
```

Comment: hi this only returns the average of the entire 2nd column and binds that to the unique values of the 1st column

what I actually need is is the average of each of the quadruplets of replicated measurements for each sample

Comment: If this is not the answer you had expected why do you have accepted the answer of Bernhard which is exactly the same as mine?

Comment: @johnnyutah the mean is calculated for each sample `AE01`, `AE02`, etc. separately, not for the entire 2nd column.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(col1) %>%
    summarise(mean_col2 = mean(col2, na.rm = TRUE))
#   col1 mean_col2
#  <chr>     <dbl>
#1  AE01     0.255
#2  AE02     0.295
```